# It there a literary technique for when authors create a language within their novel?

Tags: phrase-requests, literary-techniques

Like in 1984 when Orwell creates newspeak? I'm trying to find techniques to analyse his decision to do this...

Comment: Are you wondering about just the choice of near-English negolisms Orwell used in 1984's prose to enhance the theme of his narrative, or are more interested in created languages like Tolkien's Elvish or the modern-day Klingon?

Comment: I believe Orwell did a great service with 'newspeak' which satirised governments' and others' attempts to place a positive spin on things though the names they choose for policies, ministries, departments etc. But another very interesting language representation is given by Hemingway in 'For Whom the Bell Tolls', where he renders all the speech using English words but using Spanish speech order and constructions. It serves as a constant reminder to the reader that the characters are Spanish, not English, with Spanish values and habits of life.

Comment: Would this be better on Writers.SE?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "technique", and how it is a question about English.

Answer (score 1):

Those who have a particular interest in constructed languages often use "artistic language" to refer to those created for artistic reasons (whether the act of construction is seen as art in itself, or it serves as part of a larger artistic project like Newspeak was to *1984*).

This is often condensed to the single term *artlang* (with "constructed language" condensed to *conlang*, *auxlang*  being used for languages proposed as useful international second languages such as Interlingua or Esperanto and *logiclang* or *loglang* for languages proposed as better expressing logical connections, like Lojban and so on).

This jargon might sound a bit excessive, but then consider the community it came from.

Outside of those with a particular interest in conlangs, it's much more likely that people will just refer to them as "invented languages", "artificial languages" or "constructed languages" without the same distinction being made between the different purposes of conlangs.